# Deleting Lightning Component which is referenced previously in Community builder (currently the component is not in use)

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, community-builder, experience-builder-page, deployment-error

I am trying to delete a component 'CategoryHeader' which is referred in Experience builder, geting the following error:

```
**[LightningComponentBundle CategoryHeader] This component is found in 1 Development Instance(s) and 0 Published Instance(s). Use the following component paths to locate the component: [Development] TeamOne > Management Overview (Widget) > CategoryHeader (Panel) > CategoryHeader (LWC)**
```

In current layout we are not using CategoryHeader component, it's related code is commented out. Even though it is showing the error.

Please help me!!